# How can I simply test a method static method call using Minitest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mocha.js, chai, minitest

The class I am testing has a method:

```
def configuration_data(organization_id, plan_year_id)
  Benefit::BenefitConfiguration.new(organization_id, plan_year_id).index
end
```

I already have a separate test for the BenefitConfiguration index method, so in this case I would like to have code coverage for the configuration_data method.  Not sure what the best way to test the method to achieve code coverage is in this case.

My attempt at a test is:

```
instance = Benefit.new
index_mock = MiniTest::Mock.new
index_mock.expect :index, true
Benefit::BenefitConfiguration.any_instance.stubs(:new).returns(index_mock)
result = instance.configuration_data(1, 2)
assert_equal result, true
```

But when run, it fails inside of the actual BenefitConfiguration index method, it doesn't seem to be using the mock index return value of true.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
Benefit::BenefitConfiguration.any_instance.stubs(:new)
```

`any_instance` gets triggered when the `new` method is called on the given class... so this will match when you do something like:

```
Benefit::BenefitConfiguration.new
```

However... you are then telling it to stub over the `new` method on *an instance of* your class... so you are saying you are looking for code that does this:

```
Benefit::BenefitConfiguration.new.new
```

which isn't what you really want.

Probably you want something like:

```
Benefit::BenefitConfiguration.stubs(:new).returns(index_mock)
```